# Typescript button on click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to create a button in typescript that when clicked it runs a function, I did it but it fails in build(project in next js)

button.tsx

```
import { tw } from 'twind';

interface IButton {
  
  primary?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode | string;
  modifier?: string;
}

const Button = ({ primary, modifier, children, ...rest }: IButton) => {
  const baseStyle = `font-sans font-medium py-2 px-4 border rounded`;
  const styles = primary
    ? `bg-indigo-600 text-white border-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-700`
    : `bg-white text-gray-600 border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100`;

  return (
    <button type="button" className={tw(`${baseStyle} ${styles} ${modifier ?? ``}`)} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button> 
  );
};

export default Button;
```

and here is where I try to run the onclick function:

```
  const hey = (onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>) => {
    sendEmail()
    setText("Thank you!")
  }
            <Button onClick={hey}>{text}</Button>
```

Comment: You mention it fails when building - what error do you get? What have you tried to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the TypeChecker will fail as onClick is not part of the Button interface.

Either add only `onClick` to the `IButton` interface or use the following:

```
const Button = ({ ... }: IButton & React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>) => { ... }
```

This way you can add any props valid for `button` to your `Button`.